# Indenting template arguments in Emacs

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

I'm having no luck getting Emacs (cc-mode) to indent multiline template arguments.  Here's an example line:

```
typedef ::boost::zip_iterator< ::boost::tuple<
vector<int>::const_iterator, vector<float>::const_iterator > >;
```

I'd like the second line to be indented, as like in a function.  It is indented, until I enter the second-to-last `>`, at which point the second line up moves to the left to align with the typedef.

When I start typing the second line, the syntactic analysis is `((statement-cont 52))`, until the second-to-last `>`, at which point it becomes `((defun-block-intro 46))`.  Deleting the character doesn't return to the old syntactic analysis.

I expected to have template-args-cont as the syntactic analysis.

I'm using the emacs 22.2 (ubuntu intrepid) and cc-mode version 5.31.5 that came with it.

Answer (score 3):

You *should* just need to set `template-args-cont` to some useful value.  To experiment with it, put your cursor on the second line and enter `C-cC-o` for `c-set-offset`.  Insert a convenient value.  With 4, I get:

```
typedef ::boost::zip_iterator< ::boost::tuple<
    vector<int>::const_iterator, vector<float>::const_iterator > >;
```

If that doesn't work, check your version:  I have cc-mode version 5.31.6.  To check, do `M-x c-version`.  I get

```
Using CC Mode version 5.31.6
```

Comment: `C-cC-o` lets me change the offset for the syntactic symbol, for template-args-cont I'm already setting that in my .emacs as +, and that's the default `C-cC-o` offers to set it to.  Setting it to a number make no difference.

As best as I can tell, cc-mode isn't recognizing this line as having a template-args-cont syntax.

(I'm using cc-mode version 5.31.5.)

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is to upgrade to 5.31.6, or al least have a look at the change log.  In any case, the example up above is cut&paste from an emacs session where I did C-C C-o 4 and reindented with TAB; got identical results with indent-region.  If that doesn't work, then you may have done something artistic elsewhere in your .emacs; try staring emacs with --no-init-file and see what happens.

Comment: Except I think 5.31.6 is only bundled with Emacs 23.  It's not available for download on the cc-mode site http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/index.php .  The template-args-cont symbol was introduced 5.15, so this isn't a new feature.

I did try doing emacs --no-init-file and that didn't change the indentation.

Comment: well then you're left with an issue that it works for me and doesn't work for you.  I'm running "GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.6.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) of 2009-01-02 on seijiz.local"  You *are* reindenting the line with TAB or indent-region after you change the value, right?  It won't change the indentation until you do.

Comment: Of course.

I was afraid it was something complicated like this.  I think I just need to get emacs to recognize the syntax as template-args-cont, but I have no idea how.

Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ah.  Look at the lines above.  Any chance you're missing a ';'?  Paste in about ten lines around the line at issue and let me see them if that doesn't give you the hint you need.

Comment: CC-mode does not recognize template-args-cont in defun-block, so if the typedef is in a function, only statement-cont is effective.

Comment: Which version, Ian?  If it's the current version, that might be worth a bug report.